# Eclipse doesn't define a class

Tags: android, eclipse

There is the following class:

```
private class SimpleExistedTasksAdapter<CalendarTask> extends ArrayAdapter<CalendarTask> {

    private Context context;
    private List<CalendarTask> tasks;

        public SimpleExistedTasksAdapter(Context context,
                int textViewResourceId, List<CalendarTask> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

            this.context=context;
            this.tasks=objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.existed_tasks_item_layout, null);
            CalendarTask task=tasks.get(position);
            TextView priorityView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewPriorityColorIndicator);
            TextView title=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTaskTitle);
            task.getPriority();
            return null;
        }
}
```

And I've got the following problem: CalendarTask class has getPriority() method, but Eclipse tells me that "task" is just object and doesn't contain any methods exсept Object's ones (there is import for CalendarTask).

Comment: can you post your CalendarTask class code as well?

Comment: is the method public? can you show the code for CalendarTask?

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I messed with Java, but check the return type on the CalendarTask.get method. I suspect you may need to perform a cast from Object to CalendarTask  in the line:

```
CalendarTask task=tasks.get(position);
```

If I recall correctly, the code would look like this:

```
CalendarTask task = (CalendarTask)tasks.get(position);
```

Comment: No. It's called *generics*, and it has been part of the Java specs since 2004. It is also the greated thing since sliced bread. Not everyone likes their bread sliced, though.

Comment: Yes! but then the OP should have got a ClassCastException as well.

Comment: @Paul Jan - I like my bread sliced as much as the next guy. No need to be a condescending ass. Oops, I attempted an answer. It was wrong. I stand in absolute awe of your mastery. Jesus.

Comment: Sorry for coming across as a condescending ass.